# Как принять строчку в php

Tags: javascript, php8

```
fetch('/jx/', {body: JSON.stringify({md:'text', b:[1,2]}), method: 'POST'});
```

Допустим отправляем к php данную строчку. Вопрос в том, как в php ее вытащить и как сделать так чтобы в php преобразовать ее в массив и работать как с массивом?

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: пусто, ничего нет только do =>'jx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае будет так:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// json в массив
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```